# Sensitivity Analysis with categorical predictive variables in R

Tags: r, neural-networks, categorical-data, random-forest, sensitivity-analysis

I am doing a project where I have to predict the Sales Units in fashion and intend to run a Random Forest, Neural Networks, and Support Vector Machine models. However, my predictive variables are all categorical, such as color or price range. How can I do the sensitivity analysis of the actual values of my predictive variables in R?

For instance, if I pick the color, how do I know whether blue or yellow has a higher impact?

Comment: (1) Sensitivity analysis is something different from what you are describing (you can see the tag description), (2) You can only assess the "impact" of a variable, not of individual values of that variable.  You can determine a variable's relative importance in your model (based, for example on the change in $R^{2}$ when it's added to the model - if it's a regression).   So maybe you can clarify what your ultimate goal is.

Comment: So, if not Sensitivity Analysis, where would you fit this question into?

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to do?  When you say, "higher impact", higher impact on what?

Comment: My model will be something like:   Sales~Color + PriceRange+Category                                                                                                       So, I am predicting sales, and I have for instance color as one of my predictive variables. I want to know, within the range of colors (yellow, red, blue,...) which ones will represent higher sales and which ones will represent lower.

Comment: Isn't that just something you can do by comparing average sales across colors, or doing something like a t-test if you are looking to show statistical significance of the differences?

Comment: check page 95 of the document,
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sensitivity/sensitivity.pdf shapleySubsetMC is a variance-based method that can be used for categorical variables. Let me know if it works

Answer (score 3):

Use the function [`sobolshap_knn`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/sensitivity/versions/1.27.0/topics/sobolshap_knn) in the R package [`sensitivity`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sensitivity/) analysing global sensitivity with categorical and discrete variables.

1. First, you create dummies. For example, if you have three colours, white, red and blue, then create three dummies `X1,X2,X3` and use `(X1=1,X2=0,X3=0)` to represent white, `(0,1,0)` to represent red, and `(0,0,1)` to represent blue.
2. Then build a model with your other parameters including the three dummies. For instance, we have another parameter `X4`, and the model is for red is X4+1, for white is X4+5, for blue is X4+2, then our model is `X1*(X4+1)+X2*(X4+5)+X3*(X4+2)`.
3. Create your iterations with matrix with three columns since you have three dummies. Then make sure each row only has one value of 1 and all the rest is 0. For example, to iterate 3 times, your two matrixes could be
   [0,0,1;
   0,1,0;
   1,0,0],
   and
   [0,1,0;
   1,0,0;
   0,0,1]
4. Finally run Sobol indices with [`sobolshap_knn`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/sensitivity/versions/1.27.0/topics/sobolshap_knn). Find detailed usage in the [`sensitivity` reference manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sensitivity/sensitivity.pdf).